# PHP caesar cipher function str_replace is changing characters wrong

Tags: php, str-replace, caesar-cipher

I am trying to make a caesar cipher function with PHP but I have a problem with str_replace.

When I'm do this,

```
function evangel($data, $key) {
    $alphabet = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

    $cryptoAlphabet = array();

    for($i=0;$i<26;$i++) {
        $index = $i+$key;
        if($i+$key > 25) $index = (($i+$key)%25)-1;

        $cryptoAlphabet[$i] = $alphabet[$index];
    }

    $cryptedData = str_replace($alphabet, $cryptoAlphabet, $data);

    return $cryptedData;
}
```

It gives me these arrays;

```
$alphabet = Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e [5] => f [6] => g [7] => h [8] => i [9] => j [10] => k [11] => l [12] => m [13] => n [14] => o [15] => p [16] => q [17] => r [18] => s [19] => t [20] => u [21] => v [22] => w [23] => x [24] => y [25] => z )

$cryptoAlphabet  = Array ( [0] => b [1] => c [2] => d [3] => e [4] => f [5] => g [6] => h [7] => i [8] => j [9] => k [10] => l [11] => m [12] => n [13] => o [14] => p [15] => q [16] => r [17] => s [18] => t [19] => u [20] => v [21] => w [22] => x [23] => y [24] => z [25] => a )
```

And this output for my $data = "aacceett" and $key = 1;

```
aaaaaaaa
```

But when I'm do this;

```
function evangel($data, $key) {
    $alphabet = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

    $cryptoAlphabet = array('z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y');

    $cryptedData = str_replace($alphabet, $cryptoAlphabet, $data);

    return $cryptedData;
}
```

The arrays are declared manually but this time, for example when my $data = "ffddss";

```
eeccrr
```

The output is correct. Why when I'm changing the alphabet array automatically the str_replace function is not working?

Comment: Here's my wee interpretation: https://3v4l.org/Ov3TG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crytpo alphabet is different in each case. In the first case, the `[0]` element is `b`, and in the second, `z`. Your code produces the results it does because - for example - when it sees `a`, it replaces it with `b`, then it see that the replacement for `b` is `c`, so it does that, and so on until it runs through the entire array, eventually finishing with the replacement of `z` with `a`, so all characters in the output become `a`. In your second case, `a` is translated to `z` (which will then get translated to `y`) but all other characters are replaced with something that comes earlier in the array, so they are not replaced again.

You can work around this issue by using [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) instead. The difference between `strtr` and `str_replace` is that `strtr` will only replace a given substring once.

```
function evangel($data, $key) {
    $alphabet = range('a', 'z');
    $cryptoAlphabet = array();
    for($i=0;$i<26;$i++) {
        $index = $i+$key;
        if($i+$key > 25) $index = (($i+$key)%25)-1;

        $cryptoAlphabet[$i] = $alphabet[$index];
    }
    $cryptedData = strtr($data, array_combine($alphabet, $cryptoAlphabet));
    return $cryptedData;
}

echo evangel('aacceett', 7);
```

Output

```
hhjjllaa
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4o5IY)

Note you can simplify your definition of `$alphabet` using [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).